# sh scripting accesing global variable in a function

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, sh

I'm writing this question because I am not familiar with sh scripting but I know the following line works in /bin/bash, but I need to use /bin/sh. Below is the code:

```
#!/bin/sh

trythis=1

test()
{
  ((trythis++))
  echo $trythis
}

test
```

I would expect 2 as the output but instead I get the following error:

```
./test: 7: ./test: trythis++: not found
1
```

Comment: Use `#!/bin/bash` on top instead of `#!/bin/sh`

Comment: The problem is with the Bash syntax `((trythis++))`, not with the variable itself. As @anubhava points, do use Bash if you want to use bashisms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
((trythis++))
```

use this:

```
trythis=`expr $trythis + 1`
```

`expr(1)` is an external program that receives arguments `1`, `+`, `1`, does the calculation and prints `2`, that is assigned to `trythis` due to the backticks. (See `man expr`, try to type things like `expr 1 + 2` on the console.)

Comment: Hey that worked! Could you link or explain me why this works?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: No need for `expr`; `trythis=$((trythis + 1))` will work in any POSIX-compliant shell.